# How to work with password protected npm module?

Tags: javascript, npm

i have 3 npm modules i created.
these modules should be delivered to our clients in "package.json" so they will just "npm install".

the thing is that i want them to only download them without ability to republish them and also i want them to be protected so no one else can download them.

what is the best practice today to store these modules and make them protected?

i tried thinking on the global npm repository but they not allowed this function as much as i know.

```
try
```

Comment: If your clients can download the package and "just npm install", anyone can. I would imagine if they're willing to republish your work, they'll also publish the passwords. You could look in to license activation, sharing them via a protected git account or even just publishing them on your own (account protected) website.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/enterprise/?

Comment: @Bergi Very nice. Although I'd still combine that with something like license activation as (as far as I can guess) their clients could still share any downloaded packages.

Comment: @Lewis Anyone dedicated could remove the licence activation part from the source code. Obfuscation might deter further, but can ultimately be bypassed. I would recommend to fight intellectual property theft with lawyers, not code - especially if the clients are known.

Comment: I dont mind if they will republish the code. i care if they will edit it so i want to give them read only access...
@Bergi will enterprise license help us?